# drag and drop image from one panel to another in asp.net+jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, asp.net, c#-4.0

Consider a scenario where i have two panels

-> Div-1 i have individual images that are loaded from filesystem

-> Div-2 i have multiple asp.net panels like 6-8.

I need to drag the images from Div-1 and drop them into Div-2, with the below functionalities.

I need to drag individual images from Div-1 to the panels present in Div-2.
After dropping the images into the panels the user should  be able to move around the images to any other panel if required also if he thinks he has dragged and dropped a wrong image he should be able to remove the images so that they can be put back onto the left hand side panel.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/1xnmtyqs/13/ Check out

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>jQuery UI Droppable - Default functionality</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #draggable { width: 100px; height: 100px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px 10px 10px 0; }
  #droppable { width: 150px; height: 150px; padding: 0.5em; float: left; margin: 10px; }
  </style>
  <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#draggable" ).draggable();
    $( "#droppable" ).droppable({
      drop: function( event, ui ) {
        $( this )
          .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" )
          .find( "p" )
            .html( "Dropped!" );
      }
    });
  });
  </script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="draggable" class="ui-widget-content">
  <p>Drag me to my target</p>
</div>

<div id="droppable" class="ui-widget-header">
  <p>Drop here</p>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Source : Check out this http://jqueryui.com/droppable/

Answer (score 0):

You can implement the required by using**jquery ui Draggable ** api for the solution. It supports events that you can [check here](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/#events)

using the following code as

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
         $("#draggable").draggable();
    });
```

events provided by Draggable

```
     $( "#draggable" ).draggable({
       start: function() {
           // your logic
       },
       drag: function() {
               // your logic
       },
       stop: function() {
             // your logic
       }
       });
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Check this example:-

```
<style type="text/css">
         body
         {
             font-family: Arial;
             font-size: 10pt;
         }
         img
         {
             height: 100px;
             width: 100px;
         }
         #dvDest
         {
             border: 5px solid #ccc;
             padding:5px;
             height: 100px;
             width: 200px;
         }
     </style>

     <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.8.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
     <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.22/jquery-ui.js"></script>
     <link rel="Stylesheet" href="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.8.10/themes/redmond/jquery-ui.css" />
     <script type="text/javascript">
         $(function () {
             $("#dvSource img").draggable({
                 drag: function (event, ui) {
                     ui.helper.css("opacity", "0.7");
                 }
             });
             $("#dvDest").droppable({
                 drop: function (event, ui) {
                     if ($("#dvDest img").length == 0) {
                         $("#dvDest").html("");
                     }
                     ui.draggable.css("position", "static");
                     ui.draggable.css("opacity", "1");
                     $("#dvDest").append(ui.draggable);
                 }
             });
         });
     </script>
     <div id="dvSource">
         <img alt="" src="Your Images path" />
         <img alt="" src="Your Images path" />
     </div>
     <hr />
     <div id="dvDest">
         Drop here
     </div>
```

[Example](http://aspforums.net/Threads/532307/Drag-and-Drop-images-using-jQuery-in-ASPNet/Demos/1)

Comment: How can i do the same if lets say for every image in dvSource i have a corresponding div in the dvDest i.e. multiple div's in my destination